# Regarding implementation of Dependency Injection with C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

i never use Dependency Injection in apps. i go through few article with Dependency Injection and found the concept is interesting but believe hard to implement in real life. now i want to implement Dependency Injection in my win form apps.

our company work with many shipping company like UPS, Fedex, Purolator etc for now but in future they have plan to works with many other shipping company. i have developed separate separate class library projects for all those shipping company like UPS, Fedex, Purolator and include those dll into our main form apps. the problem is many time we hard code few things in our code like country code etc.

for example i have one form where 4 buttons are there. like those buttons are "Ship with UPS WorldShip", another button there called "Ship with UPS WebAPI", another button there called "Ship with FedEX Desktop Apps" and another last button called "Ship with Fedex WebAPI".

when user click on UPS WorldShip button then a flat file generate in a folder.
when user click on UPS WebAPI button then a request goes to UPS site.

when user click on FedEX WinApps button then a flat file generate in a folder.
when user click on FedEX WebAPI button then a request goes to FedEx site.

so what i do now when user click on any button then i call a specific function exist in dll to complete the task.

everything is working fine at my end but the problem is when our company start working with another new shipping company then i have to create another class library for that company.

i said i never use DI ever in my apps and have no experience. so some one guide me how could i handle my situation with DI as a result when a new shipping company will join then i do not have to write any extra code. so guide me how to implement DI in my apps and also guide me with how to handle my situation with sample DI code for guidance.

### My second phase question

1) when i need to call InitializeKernel()  function ? when application load or when form load

2) i am not familiar with ninject so i just do not understand what is the meaning of this line of code

.Configure((b, c) => 
b.InTransientScope().Named(c.Name)));

3) what c.Name would return?

4) i found no config file entry. ninject does not require config file entry like unity DI?

the code u gave looks very professional. if possible please answer all my points.

at last tell me is there any pdf available for ninject for learning DI and ninject code usage.

thanks

### MY 3rd phase of question

very sorry and u r right InitializeKernel() declare once.

u said Ninject supports fluent configuration only then a problem could occur because when a new shipping company join then i have to change code with in this block like

```
using(var kernel = InitializeKernel())     
{
    // 4.1 resolve delivery services by names
    var upsWorldShip = kernel.Get<IShippingCompanyService>("ShippingUpsWorldShip");
    var fedExDesktopApps = kernel.Get<IShippingCompanyService>("ShippingFedExDesktopApps");


    var PurolatorExDesktopApps = kernel.Get<IShippingCompanyService>("PurolatorFedExDesktopApps");

    // 4.2 delivery processing
    upsWorldShip.Delivery();
    fedExDesktopApps.Delivery();

    // 5 PROFIT!
}
```

so here i need to add this line

```
var PurolatorExDesktopApps = kernel.Get<IShippingCompanyService>  ("PurolatorFedExDesktopApps");
```

the problem is whenever a new shipping related dll will be added then i have to add one line of code in the above block....that is not desirable.

if i could add all dll's related info in config file and load & instantiated all classed from all dll from there it would be better. so i am looking for ur suggestion. thanks

Comment: Applying the dependency injection principle will not prevent you from having to write another library. It allows you to hide implementations behind an abstraction, make the consumers of these implementation testable, and allow you to apply cross-cutting concerns to code without having to alter original classes.

Comment: You can use nugget and install ninject its quite easy to use.

Comment: i just do not understand why negative marking for a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you're asking for [**Configuration by Convention**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). This means that you identify groups of components that should share a common configuration and then specify that configuration in a single statement once [read more about it](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/What-is-configuration-by-convention)

In practice, this mean that you'll deploy all libraries with selected functionality "delivery" into "special" location in your project, and inherit all implementation from "special" interface. Finally, make DI container to find them and configure all for you.

#### Define Convention

Here is a simple example how to achieve this using [`Ninject.Extensions.Conventions`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/What-is-configuration-by-convention).

**Pay an attention to comments**

```
// 1 define "delivery" interface
interface IShippingCompanyService
{
    void Delivery();
}

// 2.1 — first assembly "Ups.Services.dll"
public class ShippingUpsWorldShip : IShippingCompanyService
{
    public void Delivery()
    {
        "Ship with UPS WorldShip".Dump();
    }
}

// 2.2 — first assembly "FedEx.Services.dll"
public class ShippingFedExDesktopApps : IShippingCompanyService
{
    public void Delivery()
    {
        "Ship with FedEX Desktop Apps".Dump();
    }
}
```

#### Define Configuration

Build configuration using Ninject Kernel (`StandardKernel` in this case)

```
// 3 kernel configuration
public static IKernel InitializeKernel() 
{ 
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind(x => x
         // 3.1 search in current assembly
        .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses() // 3.2 select all classes implement "special" interface
            .InheritedFrom<IShippingCompanyService>()
        // 3.3 search all assemblies by wildcards
        .Join.FromAssembliesMatching("./*Services.dll")
            .SelectAllClasses() // 3.2 select all classes implement special interface
            .InheritedFrom<IShippingCompanyService>()
        // 3.4 bind to "special" interface
        .BindAllInterfaces()
        // 3.5 configure lifetime management and dependency name
        .Configure((b, c) => 
            b.InTransientScope().Named(c.Name)));

    return kernel; 
}
```

#### How to resolve dependencies

From [Composition root of application](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) resolve delivery services by names

```
// 4 from your Compositon Root ...
using(var kernel = InitializeKernel())     
{
    // 4.1 resolve delivery services by names
    var upsWorldShip = kernel.Get<IShippingCompanyService>("ShippingUpsWorldShip");
    var fedExDesktopApps = kernel.Get<IShippingCompanyService>("ShippingFedExDesktopApps");

    // 4.2 delivery processing
    upsWorldShip.Delivery();
    fedExDesktopApps.Delivery();

    // 5 PROFIT!
}
```

All sources available [here](https://gist.github.com/4502263)

#### Summary

**Configuration by Convention** is very helpful approach already adopted in many projects. Nevertheless, I recomment you to read [Mark Seemann book "Dependency Injection in .NET"](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) and watch his [talk about conventions](http://bit.ly/UkxXWG).

#### Answers

1. *when i need to call InitializeKernel() function ? when application load or when form load*,

   - at app start, at [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx)
2. *i am not familiar with ninject so i just do not understand what is the meaning of this line of code*: `.Configure((b, c) => b.InTransientScope().Named(c.Name)))`

   - Every time dependency injected, new instance will be create
   - Dependencies *could* be refered by their class name
3. *what `c.Name` would return?*

   - Class name
4. *i found no config file entry. ninject does not require config file entry like unity DI?*

   - Ninject supports fluent configuration only
5. *u declare two method of having same name called `InitializeKernel()` the 2nd `InitializeKernel()` is for what?*

   - There is only one declaration of method `InitializeKernel()`
6. *at last tell me is there any pdf available for ninject for learning DI and ninject code usage*

   - The best place to learn about Ninject is from [the official wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki)

Comment: i asked few question based on ur answer....please have a look at "My second phase question" portion in my prev question at bottom. thnx.

Comment: again i asked few thing in my 3rd phase of question. please have look and tell me what will be the fix.

Comment: There are several DI containers that support both conventions and xml  configuration, for example _Windsor IoC_, but I'm not sure about this, because have no practical expirience with it

Answer (score 1):

First there's a very nice book ["Dependency Injection in .NET" by Seemann](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)

And [here is](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) the benchmark of many DI containers.

The main idea of DI is that consumer must not create instances of the services it consumes.
And each service should be presented to the client in the most abstract way: interface/base class (in your case it is that special function).

> then i have to create another class library for that company

That is inevitable. It does matter how do you reference this new API. Client code should not be aware about implementation details.